# Converting from tsv to fasta

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

I have a bunch of TSV files in my folder and for everyone one of them I would like to get a fasta file where the header after the sign '>' is the name of the file. 
My TSV file has 5 columns without header:

Thus:

inputfile called: "A.coseq.table_headless.tsv"

`HIV1B-pol-seed  15  MAX 1959    GTAACAGACTCACAATATGCATTAGGAATCATTCAAGC`

output file called "A.fasta"

>A_MAX

GTAACAGACTCACAATATGCATTAGGAATCATTCAAGC

I want to run the script simultaneously in bash for all the files and I have this script who does not work because in awk print statement I have a curly brace:

```
for sample in `ls *coseq.table_headless.tsv`
do
base1=$(basename $sample "coseq.table_headless.tsv")
awk '{print ">"${base1}"_"$3"\n"$5}' ${base1}coseq.table_headless.tsv > ${base1}fasta

done
```

Any idea how to correct this code?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

if the basename is the part until the first ".", you can get rid of the loop as well.

```
 awk '{split(FILENAME,base,"."); 
       print ">" base[1] "_" $3 "\n" $5 > base[1]".fasta"}' *coseq.table_headless.tsv
```

Comment: Perhaps wait little more for anothre answer and https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Another ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ pfx=substr(FILENAME,1,index(FILENAME,".")-1); 
       printf(">%s_%s\n%s\n",pfx,$3,$5) > pfx".fasta" }' *coseq.table_headless.tsv
```

---

- `pfx` contains the first part of *filename* (till the 1st `.`)

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions posted so far have a few issues:

1. not closing the files as they're written will produce "too many
   open files" errors unless you use GNU awk,
2. calculating the output file name every time a line is
   read rather than once when the input file is opened is inefficient, and
3. using parenthesized expression on the right side of output
   redirection is undefined behavior and so will only work in some awks
   (including GNU awk).

This will work robustly and efficiently in all awks:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { close(out); f=FILENAME; sub(/\..*/,"",f); pfx=">"f"_"; out=f".fasta" }
    { print pfx $3 ORS $5 > out }
' *coseq.table_headless.tsv
```